# Using django-easy_pdf package on django, long content is hiding not generating multiple pages

Tags: python, html, django, pdf

I'm trying to display content on multiple pages using the django-easy_pdf package, but, when the content is very long, this content is hiding, only the first page is displayed ( without the content ), I can't display the content on multiple pages.

If the content is short, then, this is displayed without problems, but, only display one page.

what is wrong ?

This is my code:

- [Base template ( called pdf_base.html, this is my custom base layout )](https://pastebin.com/W0JH6NsT)
- [This is my custom view ( called: pdf.html )](https://pastebin.com/7GeX8XZT)
- This is my view

  ```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
  class HelloPDFView(PDFTemplateResponseMixin, DetailView):
      template_name = 'budgets/pdf.html'
      model = Budget
      slug_field = 'id'
  ```
- This is my url: `url(r'^budgets/(?P<slug>\d+)/pdf/$', HelloPDFView.as_view(), name='budgets_pdf' )`

thanks!.

Comment: Hi everyone, I can fix it, I changed the package to generate pdf, I used the package called 'djangopisa' and done, I've my pdf desireed,  thanks to all